# Gtk3 ProgressBar C. CSS/styling issues, progress bar is too thin

Tags: css, c, gtk, progress-bar, glade

I'm using C, GTK3 (debian jessie updated GTK to 3.14), Glade and CSS. I made a simple window with a GtkProgressBar and a few buttons to initiate and stop the progression, it all worked perfectly, but I thought that the progress bar was to thin so I've decided to make it bigger with CSS. But I could not use any kind of CSS height propriety without having an warning like `(progress:1722): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: progress.css:17:14: 'min-height' is not a valid property name`. And I do can change colors, include border size/color/radius, everything but not the size of the progress bar itself, I've read and tried all styling options in the [Developer Gnome ProgressBar page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkProgressBar.html#GtkProgressBar--s-min-horizontal-bar-height) (which are not many) and some CSS ones including these down below and a few others:

```
    -GtkProgressBar-min-horizontal-bar-height: 10px;

    min-height: 10px;

    height: 10px;    

    background-size: 30px 30px; /*Just trying...*/
```

but every one of those gives me same kind of warning, so my question is: Is it possible to make progress bar thicker while using Gtk3, Glade, C and CSS?

Comment: Please add the warnings to the question. They are trying to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: The warning is right there, all I got its `min-height`or `height`followed by `is not a valid property name` ....I told that in the question

Comment: And what is wrong it is the GTK version itself, on Windows I'm using GTK 3.20 and this problem doesn't happen, the problem is with the 3.14 version of GTK, which is the most updated on Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer will help in your case (depends on which GTK version you're using): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49367990/547270

```
progress, trough {
  min-height: 1.2em;
}
```

The `progress` selector corresponds to the level of progress (the blue stripe) and `trough` corresponds to the progress bar background.

Note: this also affects other widgets such as `GtkScale`. To overcome this, you'd also need:

```
scale > trough {
  min-height: 0.1em;
}
```