# Gtk Progress bar height

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'm developing a Gtk application in c++. (Gtk 3.0). My problem is that I can't change ProgressBar height!
(https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkProgressBar.html)

The picture below will show what I need. In general I would like to have a possibility to set up height of progress bar in my code.[progress bar height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Xmz.png)

I'm using following command to compile my example:

```
gcc progress.cpp `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

This the sample of my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean
fill (gpointer   user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *progress_bar = user_data;

  /*Get the current progress*/
  gdouble fraction;
  fraction = gtk_progress_bar_get_fraction (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (progress_bar));

  /*Increase the bar by 10% each time this function is called*/
  fraction += 0.1;

  /*Fill in the bar with the new fraction*/
  gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (progress_bar), fraction);

  /*Ensures that the fraction stays below 1.0*/
  if (fraction < 1.0) 
    return TRUE;

  return FALSE;
}


static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *progress_bar;

  gdouble fraction = 0.0;

  /*Create a window with a title, and a default size*/
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "ProgressBar Example");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 220, 20);

  /*Create a progressbar and add it to the window*/
  progress_bar = gtk_progress_bar_new ();
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), progress_bar);

  /*Fill in the given fraction of the bar. Has to be between 0.0-1.0 inclusive*/
  gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (progress_bar), fraction);

  /*Use the created fill function every 500 milliseconds*/
  g_timeout_add (500, fill, GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (progress_bar));

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}


int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Comment: You will need to use CSS for this. See the [GtkProgressBar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkProgressBar.html#GtkProgressBar.style-properties) [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkProgressBar.html#GtkProgressBar.description) for details. Note that if you need to run on GTK+ 3.18 or earlier, you'll also need to provide alternates with slightly different selectors; these aren't as well documented. I don't know what the magic incantations are off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: Also note that every theme uses a different height by default, so IDK what the best "general" option is (for instance, to make it as tall as a button).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I've modified my style.css by adding


GtkProgressBar {
      -GtkProgressBar-min-horizontal-bar-height: 30px;
}

And it made my day :)

Answer (score 6):

For GTK 3.20 and newer, when defining the CSS, it seems that, instead of using the `progressbar` class, you must use the `progress` and `trough` classes.  This is what worked for me:

```
progress, trough {
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I use `em` instead of `px`, I think it's better. For example: `progress, trough {min-height: 0.5em;}`

Answer (score 0):

As document said, progressbar has 3 sub node:

```
> progressbar[.osd]
├── [text]
╰── trough[.empty][.full]
    ╰── progress[.pulse]
```

so you can write css in this style:

```
progressbar {
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

progressbar > trough {
    min-height: 80px;
    background-color: white;
}

progressbar > trough > progress {
    min-height: 80px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

progressbar > text {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: xx-large;
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

If you apply css by this function

```c
gtk_style_context_add_provider();
```

progress bar's sub-node style (trough, text and progress) defined in css may not work, I use this function instead:

```c
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display();
```